# Atom Typescript Not Displaying Errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I'm having a problem where Atom isn't displaying Typescript errors. Below is a screenshot of my code example in Atom.

[image]

And below is a screenshot of the same code in Visual Studio Code.

[image]

How can I get Atom to display the same errors like Visual Studio Code does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom requires a plugin in order to provide these errors. Install [Atom TypeScript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) (`apm install atom-typescript`) and restart Atom and the errors will automatically be displayed.

If the errors are still not showing up, you may need to manually install linter in order to show the errors (`apm install linter`). However this should be automatically handled by Atom Typescript.

You may also want to install `linter-tslint` to enable the tslint integration which comes built in for Visual Studio Code, though this is not required.

[image: example code]

Comment: I installed `linter-tslint` and that gave me the Visual Studio Code details. Had to restart a few times to get it to work tho. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

To get showing errors working, I had to reload Atom (on OSX) via View > Developer > Reload Window. A simple restart of Atom didn't work. After hitting "Reload Window", additional dependencies were loaded.