# Unable to see errors in my JavaScript code in atom

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, linter

Atom editor is not showing errors in my javascript code.

I already installed packages such as linter-jshint and linter-eslint, linter,linter-jscs, but I didn't set any executable path in these packages.

It is showing default. Is the problem with the path, if it is, can u tell me what and how to set the path? If there is any another problem , please tell me and make my atom work perfectly.

Comment: what error you have that should have been shown but it isn't?

Comment: This ? https://discuss.atom.io/t/javascript-errors-not-detected/58963/2

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296815/atom-typescript-not-displaying-errors